# How to install jython 2.7?

Tags: package-management, python, java, ppa, jython

How do I install `Jython 2.7`?

```
thufir@doge:~$ jython --version
"my" variable $jythonHome masks earlier declaration in same scope at /usr/bin/jython line 15.
Jython 2.5.3
thufir@doge:~$ cat /etc/lsb-release 
DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=16.10
DISTRIB_CODENAME=yakkety
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 16.10"
```

Is there perhaps a particular package which will install 2.7, or another repo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To install Jython 2.7:

- Download it from their [official website](http://www.jython.org/downloads.html)
- Double click the `jython_installer-2.7.0.jar` or run `java -jar jython_installer-2.7.0.jar`. For headless mode add `--console`.

The installer will then walk through a similar set of steps in graphical or console mode: showing the license, selecting an install directory and JVM and actually copying Jython to the filesystem. After this completes, Jython is installed in the directory you selected. Executing a script in the install directory, jython on Unix-like systems, will start up the Jython console, which can be used to dynamically explore Jython and the Java runtime, or to run Jython scripts.

---

Source: http://www.jython.org/ and https://wiki.python.org/jython/InstallationInstructions

Comment: The Jython devs are geniuses but they don't keep things up-to-date: https://github.com/jythontools/jython (--> "releases") is the best place to go for the latest version, at time of writing 2.7.2a (which you wouldn't know from the official website)

Answer (score 1):

[Ubuntu Artful (17.10) has jython version 2.7.1](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/jython).

So just [upgrade](https://askubuntu.com/questions/110477/how-do-i-upgrade-to-a-newer-version-of-ubuntu) to that.